# Correct approach or design pattern to simplify the `operatorX` functions in a class to compare attributes of the same type in a given order?

Tags: c++, c++11, design-patterns, comparison, operators

In the past I reduced the repetition in `operator<`, `<=`, `>` and `>=` functions of data type classes by writing a helper function which takes a comparison function as argument.

Simplified, a such class looks like this:

```
class Foo {
public:
    bool comparison(const Foo &other, std::function<bool(int a, int b)> compFn) {
        if (_a == other._a) {
            if (_b == other._b) {
                 return compFn(_c, other._c);
            }
            return compFn(_b, other._b);
        }
        return compFn(_a, other._a);
    }
    bool operator<(const Foo &other) const {
        return comparison(other, [](int a, int b){return a<b;})
    }
    bool operator<=(const Foo &other) const {
        return comparison(other, [](int a, int b){return a<=b;})
    }
    bool operator>(const Foo &other) const {
        return comparison(other, [](int a, int b){return a>b;})
    }
    bool operator>=(const Foo &other) const {
        return comparison(other, [](int a, int b){return a>=b;})
    }
private:
    int _a;
    int _b;
    int _c;
};
```

The real classes use complexes data types, but the principle stays the same. The comparison less or greater is a comparison of a number of attributes in a given order.

Using the `comparison` function I can change this order at any time, just rewriting a single function. Also the logic is at a single point and not repeated in four places.

**Is there a established design pattern to cover this situation?**

I realised that there are already the comparison objects, like `std::less`. But I could not find a simple way to use them instead instead of the shown solution.

**Can the shown solution further simplified using other language features or the standard library?**

Comment: The [Barton-Nackman](https://en.wikibooks.org/wiki/More_C%2B%2B_Idioms/Barton-Nackman_trick) trick is probably relevant.

Answer (score 2):

Your implementation looks a bit complicated for me...

I would try to solve the problem using [`std::tie`](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/utility/tuple/tie) as follows:

```
class Foo {
public:    
    bool operator<(const Foo &other) const {
        return std::tie(_a, _b, _c) <
            std::tie(other._a, other._b, other._c);
    }

    bool operator<=(const Foo &other) const {
        return std::tie(_a, _b, _c) <=
            std::tie(other._a, other._b, other._c);
    }

    bool operator>(const Foo &other) const {
        return !(*this <= other);
    }

    bool operator>=(const Foo &other) const {
        return !(*this < other);
    }

private:
    int _a;
    int _b;
    int _c;
};
```

Comment: Wouldn't you use `std::make_tuple` in this case?

Comment: @Flovdis `std::tie` is more optimal than `std::make_tuple`, that's what @Holt mentioned in the comments earlier. It avoids unnecessary copying and, basically, writing comparison operators via `std::tie` is a more or less common practice, AFAIK.

Answer (score 1):

You can use **Curiously Recurring template pattern** in combination with **Barton-Nackman** trick. 
You only need to define 1 comparation function in your classes that returns:

```
< 0   if a < b
> 0   if a > b
== 0  if a == b
```

When a class template is instantiated the in-class friend definitions produce operator definitions.

Normal Runtime polymorphism without CRTP would also work.

You can change the comparation logic in the Cmp(...) however you want, and the operator functions are playing nicely. I provided also small example: one default and inverted comparation.

```
#include <iostream>
#include <iomanip>
#include <tuple>

using namespace std;

template<typename T>
struct Comparable {
  friend bool operator==(const T& lft, const T& rgt) {
    return lft.Cmp(rgt) == 0;
  }

  friend bool operator<(const T& lft, const T& rgt) {
    return lft.Cmp(rgt) < 0;
  }

  friend bool operator>(const T& lft, const T& rgt) {
    return lft.Cmp(rgt) > 0;
  }

  friend bool operator!=(const T& lft, const T& rgt) {
    return !operator==(lft, rgt);
  }

  friend bool operator<=(const T& lft, const T& rgt) {
    return !operator>(lft, rgt);
  }

  friend bool operator>=(const T& lft, const T& rgt) {
    return !operator<(lft, rgt);
  }
};

class Foo : public Comparable<Foo> {

  private:
    static int cmpMode_;

  public:
    static void SetDefaultComparator() { cmpMode_ = 1; }
    static void SetInvertedComparator() { cmpMode_ = -1; }

  public:
    Foo() : a_{0}, b_{0}, c_{0} {}
    Foo(int a, int b, int c) : a_{a}, b_{b}, c_{c} {}

    // return  < 0   if lhs < rhs
    // return == 0   if lhs == rhs
    // return > 0    if lhs > rhs
    int Cmp(const Foo& rhs) const {
      auto t1 = std::tie(a_, b_, c_);
      auto t2 = std::tie(rhs.a_, rhs.b_, rhs.c_);
      auto cmp = t1 < t2 ? -1 : (t1 > t2 ? 1 : 0);
      return cmpMode_ * cmp;
    }

  private:
    int a_;
    int b_;
    int c_;
};  // Foo

int Foo::cmpMode_ = 1;

int main() {

  Foo f1{1,1,1};
  Foo f2{1,1,1};
  Foo f3{1,1,2};
  Foo f4{1,2,1};

  Foo::SetDefaultComparator();

  cout << endl << "Using default comparator: " << endl;
  cout << boolalpha
    << "f1 == f2 ? " << (f1 == f2) << endl
    << "f1 != f2 ? " << (f1 != f2) << endl
    << "f2 < f3 ? " << (f2 < f3) << endl
    << "f2 <= f3 ? " << (f2 <= f3) << endl
    << "f3 > f4 ? " << (f3 > f4) << endl
    << "f3 >= f4 ? " << (f3 >= f4) << endl
    << "f4 > f3 ? " << (f4 >= f4) << endl;


  Foo::SetInvertedComparator();

  cout << endl << "Using inverted comparator: " << endl;
  cout << boolalpha
    << "f1 == f2 ? " << (f1 == f2) << endl
    << "f1 != f2 ? " << (f1 != f2) << endl
    << "f2 < f3 ? " << (f2 < f3) << endl
    << "f2 <= f3 ? " << (f2 <= f3) << endl
    << "f3 > f4 ? " << (f3 > f4) << endl
    << "f3 >= f4 ? " << (f3 >= f4) << endl
    << "f4 > f3 ? " << (f4 >= f4) << endl;
}
```

Here the live demo: https://wandbox.org/permlink/uteFqj0DhSaBqxfb

Answer (score 0):

You need operator spaceship '<=>' which is scheduled into c++2x, I think. :-) Real name threeWay.

Certainly, that would be the right pattern to use, as you can migrate to it when it gets here.

Basically, <=> returns 0 if the arguments are equal, -1 if they compare "less", +1 if they are "greater". See strcmp() for an example.

You can either choose to implement <=> using = and >, then all your other operators call <=>, or implement <=> directly and have /all/ other operators simply call that.

Comment: The question is tagged C++11. Though you are correct that's what `<=>` aims to solve.

Comment: Yes, but it is a perfectly fine design approach to take, even though you can't directly use it :-), and @Edgar was after a design.

Comment: The `<=>` operation would actually be the solution for this issue, but I have to work with C++11 at the moment.